# how to use Windows Installer XML?

Tags: c#, wpf, wix

hi guyz i tried to search for sample on how to create deployment software using windows installer xml. in visual studio 2010.. wpf.. but it's so hard for me to understand.... i dont know how and where to start... what program im going to use.... coz as far as is know, this windos installer xml is a coded type of deployment.. unlike installaware or installshield.. your just going to click/add files and automatically detect the dependency.... guyz anyone? may you can help me out of this.. thanks.. and can you give me and idea which is best the WIX or installshield or other deployment software? thanks :)

Comment: I cannot believe how stupid these guys to close this question. Shame on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Wix is a very powerful  piece of software. Not for the faint hearted I tell you, steep learning curve in which I struggle with daily but this tutorial helped me loads.

Its a great starting point http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/

Hope this helps you. First of all download the Wix 3.6 toolset as it is the latest stable release. Then go into VS2010 and click new - project - Windows installer Xml - Setup Project.

This will give you the bare bones of the project and the tutorial will help you create a simple MSI installer..:)

Comment: hi nc1 thanks for the reply.. so inorder for me to create a setup... im going to search all the dependency and one by one? like for example ummm? the .net 4 framework, the mysql etc.

Comment: Yes this is an example of looking for the .net framework http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/read_a_registry_entry.htm

Comment: wuhuuuuu.. ok ok thanks you so much.. can i mark this later as an answer? if you dont mind? coz i still have a lots of question about this.. gosh... i thought it's easy a vb6 and then using deployment package wizard... but im wrong.. aaaahhhh so i will start in a scratch... thanks again.. :)

Comment: sorry for another question... :) ummm how should i know the dependency of my application...? for example i created in c# wpf.... where can i find the list of the dependency of my apps?

Comment: Mark away..:) I also had many doubts at the beginning..trust me..:) but now that I have been doing it I even find it enjoyable..:) also sign up to the wix users mailing list. You can ask questions here and also the questions are sent to your email so you always know what people talking about because more than likely you will hit these errors yourself. http://wix.sourceforge.net/mailinglists.html

Comment: Not 100% sure as I having used that..sorry..:(

Comment: It's your job as a developer to know your dependencies.  First, what version of .NET are you using?  That's a biggie.  Then, what are your project references? Are any of them not part of the base class libraries?  Do you  have any P/Invoke?  How about file read/write (configuration data), registry, environment variables, and so on?  This is all part of requirements gathering and is a prereq to actually writing the installer.